# jqGrid overlay disabling the rest of my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jqgrid

I'm having a problem with jqGrid disabling the rest of my page. In other posts it says people forgot to load the specific jqGrid .css but I think I do have that one actually loaded. The grid is styled with a themeroller.

I import the following css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/css/ui.jqgrid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
```

This all makes it I cant access / click my other controls:
[image: Text]

Can anybody tell me what I'm missing?
Thanks in advance,
Sander

Comment: Have you tried importing `jqgrid.css` after `jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css` ?

Comment: @BatuZet Yes I've tried that and it yields the same result. I also tried removing the class which is responsible for this (lui_grid) with:
     $('#lui_grid').removeClass('ui-widget-overlay jqgrid-overlay'); which also does nothing :/

Comment: It seems that piece of code worked while posting it directly underneath the jqGrid intialisation. So it's been done now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added: `$('#lui_grid').removeClass('ui-widget-overlay jqgrid-overlay');` after the JQGrid initialization. It's fixed now.

Comment: Even though this will work, this is not the correct way. If you don't have ui.jqgrid.css in your project this issue will arise. https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/css/ui.jqgrid.css